# What's Tick effect?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Trinkets are available in Wrath of the Lamb?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71059/which-trinkets-are-available-in-wrath-of-the-lamb)

I just found this strange thing called **Tick** in Cellar level. Its stay on player head but it also shown to the top-left side of the screen. What's its purpose (I died next room without being able to see any effects)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Trinkets):

> Prevents Player from changing his/her Trinket, unless they have Mom's Purse. In return, reduces the health of all bosses by what appears to be 10-15%. (This also affects bosses encountered at random through normal rooms)

Answer (score 0):

It makes bosses spawn with less health, however cannot be traded for another trinket.